# forbidden 4.3 error on apache in ubuntu for my flask script

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I created my flask service and hosted in apache by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)  but after configuring When I go to my localhost it says,

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.18
>   (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Please help.

apache2.conf file:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

`etc/apache2/sites-available/flask.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName 192.168.175.35
            ServerAdmin pechi@email.com
            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/flask/flask.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/flask/flask/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/flask/flask/static
            <Directory /var/www/flask/flask/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help, thanks in advance!. Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: Try disabling default config `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`

Comment: `Site 000-default already disabled`

Comment: ``ServerName`` shouldn't be an IP address. If you have any other active ``VirtualHost`` in the configuration it will use the first found and not this one because name based virtual hosting can't match an IP address.

Comment: Also don't use ``Order/Allow`` as that is Apache 2.2 and older. Use ``Require all granted`` because if backward compatibility module not enabled, the old directives may not do anything.